# Specify the path where to put a downloaded file with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a python package called ete3 and in the process I need to download a huge database by using this command:

```
from ete3 import NCBITaxa
ncbi = NCBITaxa()
ncbi.update_taxonomy_database()
```

But I do not know how to specify the path where to put all the files downloaded? By default they are placed where the memory availability is small.

Does anyone have an idea?

Here is the page with all the informations of the package:
http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_ncbitaxonomy.html#id1

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you provided, it seems to all the files downloaded are stored in your home directory `~/.etetoolkit/taxa.sqlite`. It might be hidden because it is a configuration file but you can access it freely on the terminal or set your files explorer UI to display hidden files.

Comment: And do you know if I can change this path instead of juste moving this file after the download process?

Comment: Since you know where the files are located, you can setup your program to move it to your desired location during runtime with `shutil.move(<src>, <dest>)` function.

Comment: I think there's usually a configuration file that you can change your download location but I can't find any in the documentation so I don't think it is possible for this package for to change it.